# Как склеить строку и вывод функциии length?

Tags: c++

На [с++](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b) не могу понять как можно склеить строку сущность `std::string` с выводом функции `length` от другой переменной.

```
std::string str="blah blah",vstr;

vstr="text len:" + str.length() + "\n";
vstr+=str;
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку несоответствии типов(((

Comment: Хотя бы преобразовать число в строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если Вы используете более-менее современный компилятор, то Вам нужен [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

```
vstr="text len:" + to_string(str.length()) + "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете несовременный компилятор, то Вам нужен [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream stream;
stream << "text len:" << str.length() << "\n";
vstr = stream.str();
```

**PS:** Если очень хочется выглядеть современно, то можно написать свой собственный `toString` <strike>c азартными играми и доступными женщинами</strike>:

```
template<class T>
std::string toString(const T &value){
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << value;

    return stream.str();
}
```

Тогда можно сделать так как предложил [**KoVadim**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684329/191211)