# Преобразование типов в с++. Из int в string

Tags: c++, строки

Каким способами можно выполнить преобразование из инта в строку?

На сайте http://ru.cppreference.com пишут про **to_string**, но у меня компилятор выдает ошибку "'to_string' was not declared in this scope". Хотя заголовок string подключен, а так же включен с+11.

Компилятор: MinGW

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n; cin >> n;

    multiset<int> a;
    multiset<int> forCheck;
    vector<string> ans;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        int x; cin >> x;
        a.insert(x);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(forCheck.empty())
        {
            forCheck.insert(*a.begin());
            a.erase(*a.begin());
            continue;
        }
        if(*forCheck.begin() < *a.begin())
        {
            forCheck.insert(*a.begin());
            a.erase(*a.begin());
        }
        else
        {
            forCheck.clear();
        }
        if(forCheck.size() == 3)
        {
            string s = "";
            for(int i: forCheck)
                s += to_string(i); // тут!

            ans.push_back(s);
            forCheck.clear();
        }
    }

    for(string str: ans){
        cout << str;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А `using namespace std`?

Comment: @Byulent пространство имён std тоже подключил

Comment: Добавте код и строку компиляции.

Comment: @0xdb сделано!!

Comment: А строку компилятора? "а так же включен с+11"  - именно так и включили?

Comment: Вам просто попалась версия MinGW в котрой еще не успели реализовать `std::to_string`.

Comment: Выполните - `g++ --version`

Comment: @Abyx mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 C:\Users\varfa\Desktop\cpp\08\hw\4.cpp -o C:\Users\varfa\Desktop\cpp\08\hw\4.o
Версия: mingw32-g++.exe (tdm-1) 4.9.2

Comment: [Посмотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684317/Как-склеить-строку-и-вывод-функциии-length/684389#684389)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Остается предположить, что в компиляторе не реализована функция `to_string`. Ну, так ее недолго и самому написать, например, так:

```
string to_string(int n)
{
    char buf[40];
    sprintf(buf,"%d",n);
    return buf;
}
```

Или так:

```
string to_string(int n)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << n;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, в моей версии MinGW не было реализации to_string :/ Обновился до 15.0, и всё работает