# Int перевести в string

Tags: c++

Есть переменная:

```
int a = 5;
```

нужно сделать чтобы 5 перевелось в строку

```
string c = int a;
```

только так не работает, а как сделать чтобы работало, если так вообще можно сделать

Comment: Конечно же можно тем более в C++. Но канкретно сказать не могу потомучто не пользуюсь C. В Java это делаеться String.valueOf (a) или a.toString (). Посмотри методы и не торопись задавать вопрос. Я сто процентова уверен что нашел бы ты ответ и в гугл

Comment: `с = to_string(a);`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687242 взгляни сюда

Answer (score 1):

[Функции для конвертации численных типов в строки](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;

    std::string str;
    str = std::to_string(a); //преобразование из числа в строку

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```